# Using Powershell is there a way to write to Memory Address?

Tags: powershell, memory, com, port

I am trying to use [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to Flash Firmware on my ESP8266 Board.

This is basic code I have thus far:

```
# Read file to an array of bytes:
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("PathToBinFile")

# Init Com Port and Connect, send data:
$port1 = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COMX,74880,None,8,one
$port1.Open()
$port1.Write( $bytes )
$port1.ReadExisting()
$port1.Close()
```

Now, I need to be able to write to a specific Memory Address: **0x00000**

I cant find documentation showing how to do this! Can anyone help?